# How resolve my query wrong when update columns

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sql-update

I have this code:

```
@selected_ids = params[:authorization][:contract_number]
@selected_ids.zip(params[:authorization][:contract_number]).each do |id, value|
        Authorization.where(contract_number: params[:authorization][:contract_number]).update_all(value_solve: params[:authorization][:value_solve], situation: 2)
      end
```

Haven't error, but in my console generate the query

```
Processing by RefinancingsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search_employee_by_cpf"=>"11111111111", "authorization"=>{"value_solve"=>["", "4345", "454", ""], "contract_number"=>["22", "33"]}, "commit"=>"Reserve"}
  SQL (344.2ms)  UPDATE "authorizations" SET "value_solve" = '---
- ''''
- ''4345''
- ''454''
- ''''
', "situation" = 2 WHERE "authorizations"."contract_number" IN ('22', '33')
  SQL (133.1ms)  UPDATE "authorizations" SET "value_solve" = '---
- ''''
- ''4345''
- ''454''
- ''''
', "situation" = 2 WHERE "authorizations"."contract_number" IN ('22', '33')
```

And on my database, the values are duplicated for each checkbox checked.

This example is column value_solve, authorization id 2

```
---
- ''
- '4345'
- '454'
- ''
```

column value_solve, authorization id 3

```
---
- ''
- '4345'
- '454'
- ''
```

Please, just this, how I do for resolve this and save correctly on DB?
I need this:

```
SQL (344.2ms)  UPDATE "authorizations" SET "value_solve" = "4345", "situation" = 2 WHERE "authorizations"."contract_number" IN '22'
      SQL (133.1ms)  UPDATE "authorizations" SET "value_solve" = "454", "situation" = 2 WHERE "authorizations"."contract_number" IN '33'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer this is:

```
      auth_params = params[:authorization]
auth_params[:contract_number].zip(auth_params[:value_solve].reject(&:blank?)).each do |contract_number, value_solve|
          Authorization.where(contract_number: contract_number).update_all(value_solve: value_solve, situation: 2)
      end
```

:D

Answer (score 0):

You need to break that out into two updates, not one update with an array value:

```
auth_params = params[:authorization]
auth_params[:contract_number].zip(auth_params[:value_solve]).each do |contract_number, value_solve|
    Authorization.where(contract_number: contract_number).update_all(value_solve: value_solve, situation: 2)
end
```

That should fire two updates with the correct arguments.

Comment: Don't worked... Have this error: Attribute was supposed to be a Array, but was a String. -- "5745". In .where query

Comment: It looks like you might have to clean up your input parameters. This might not be a complete solution but it should do the two updates you're asking for.

Comment: I confess I do not know what to do, man. I spent a lot of time trying to work it =(